# The "field hides another field" warning in java - Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, warnings, compiler-warnings

I'm coding two classes.

```
public class ServerPanel extends JPanel{

private EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();
(...)
}
```

And

```
public class DetailsPanel extends JPanel{

private EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();
(...)
}
```

now, Netbeans is warning me for field hides another field, for the listenerList variable.

So my question is, is this a serious problem? Will I have problems later on when adding / removing events?

Is this good java practicing?

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Avoid "redefining" fields except if it is what is really desired. Keep names distinct to avoid confusion - and it makes it easier for documentation lookups. In any case, the JPanel/superclass code won't be affected (because only methods can be virtual) so nothing will suddenly break unless the superclass's `listenerList` was intended to be used from the redefining class (or subclass).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a compile error, and the two fields are treated separately, so nothing will break.  However, I would not recommend doing this because it could be very confusing to anyone working on the code, including you.

You should also know that you won't be replacing the `listenerList` field in the superclass, just creating a new one with the same name.

**[EDIT]**

I should clarify; the names aren't *exactly* the same; the fully qualified names are different:

```
javax.swing.JPanel.listenerList
whatever.yourpackageis.ServerPanel.listenerList
whatever.yourpackageis.DetalsPanel.listenerList
```

Comment: What a very good "feature" [sarcasm] of the java language. Same name, but not the same attribute, and the compiler doesn't complain about it, nice !

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html

> Hiding Fields
>
> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the
>   superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are
>   different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be
>   referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed
>   through super, which is covered in the next section. Generally
>   speaking, we don't recommend hiding fields as it makes code difficult
>   to read.